# how to show first name of a customer with HTML using ${contact.firstName} in netsuite

Tags: html, netsuite

i am trying create a html page in netsuite for showing the details of a customer and also i want to pass this value to a javascript variable. please help with this

```
var fname = ${contact.firstName};

<p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin-top:0;">Dear <h1>${contact.firstName}</h1>,</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use Attributes Tag

Syntax:

```
<%=getAttribute('recordtype',id,'attribute')%>
```

In your case you can do something like this :

```
<%=getCurrentAttribute('customer','firstname')%>
<%=getCurrentAttribute('customer','companyname')%>
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: HI YNK, thank you for your quick reply. i m trying this on a netsuite enrmnt so if i pass this in my HTML code it will print only the code. i want to print the actually value that passed by netsuite.

Comment: You can use it within a netsuite template only, and it will work after you login as a netsuite customer on website page, like : <div id="name"> <%= getCurrentAttribute("customer","firstname")%></div>  OR you can create custom tag, and just put it in your netsuite template where you want to display.

Comment: Thank you very much. i have a doubt in this answer because all the other tutorial telling me to use the freemarker tool to get a customer name. if i use <div id="name"> <%= getCurrentAttribute("customer","firstname")%></div> this how they covert this into ${contact.firstName} in netsuite. please help me